# Is there a way to list open files and order them in ascending order of time modified?

Tags: linux, bash, lsof

I'm getting `Too Many Open Files` issue even when I'm closing all files and connections I'm opening and when I've set the soft and hard limit to max available i.e. `65535`.
So in order to debug, I'm trying to re-order the output of `lsof` in terms of time.

Comment: The lsof command ordered by PID as ascending as default. Now you must be knowing ordering PID or Time are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the strace/ltrace is overkill, consider inspecting the /proc/PID/fd folder. Each entry modification time will show the timestamp that the FD was created, effectively the open/connect/accept time:

```
# X_PID is the PID of the process to monitor/check
ls -lt --time-style=full-iso /proc/$X_PID/fd
```

Sample Output

```
total 0
lrwx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:25:14.359506339 +0300 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:25:14.359506339 +0300 1 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:25:32.183370423 +0300 11 -> /tmp/a
l-wx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:26:47.862798157 +0300 15 -> /tmp/b
l-wx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:26:47.862798157 +0300 16 -> /tmp/a
l-wx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:27:20.918550476 +0300 17 -> /tmp/a
lrwx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:25:14.359506339 +0300 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 owner owner 64 2019-10-16 16:25:14.359506339 +0300 255 -> /dev/pts/0
```

Comment: Is the timestamp modification time or created time?

Comment: @umarr - on my system it is the 'open' time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the launch command, consider using strace/ltrace. It can show you each file open/close.

```
# When using ltrace, specify stdlib functions to monitor
ltrace -e open+close YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
OR
# Modern linux system will use openat system call to open a file
strace -e openat,close YOUR_COMMAND_HERE
```

You can also attach strace (and ltrace) to a running process (see man page)

If you know that you have unclosed (network) connections (and not files), consider extending/replacing the filter to focus on accept (inbound connection), connect (outbound connection) as needed.